# In Karate DSL, How do I resolve an Unsupported Media Type for a valid POST REQUEST

Tags: rest, http, http-status-codes, karate

So I created a dynamic POST Request using the features in Karate. I tested out the newly created request manually and It did return a 200. However, when running the request through Karate, I am getting a 415 Unsupported media type.

POST REQUEST:

```
{
  "content": [
    {
      "assetId": "273108817",
      "country" : "US",
      "sourceSystemCode" : "GE_Clarify",
      "serviceRequestCode" : "Karate-Insert: 157264280",
      "serviceRequestTypeCode" : "servicerequestcorrective",
      "serviceRequestStatusCode" : "Started",
      "requester" : "Karate,DSL",
      "problem" : "Submitted Using Karate",
      "submissionTimestamp" : null,
      "sourceUpdateDate": "2017-09-13T15:53:51.597Z",
      "completionDate" : null,
      "dueDate" : null,
      "availabilityDate" : null,
      "remotely" : "0",
      "assetAvailability" : "Up",
      "facilityCode" : "US_294629"
    }
  ]
}
```

Karate Syntax

Scenario: Submit a new Service Request POST:

- def ServiceRequestPostTemplate = read('classpath:testsuite/testdata/ServiceRequestServiceTemplate.json')
      * replace ServiceRequestPostTemplate
                  |       token               |   value                                     |
                  |       assetId             |   assetTblAssetId                           |
                  |       country             |   country                                   |
                  |       sourceSystemCode    |   sourceSystemCode                          |
                  |       serviceRequestCode  |   'Karate-Insert: ' + NewServiceRequestCode |

  Given path 'serviceRequests/'
  And request ServiceRequestPostTemplate

  - header Authorization = 'Bearer ' + Token
    When method post
    Then status 200

Error message in below attachment. Note, I checked the request manually through Swagger UI and everything worked fine. I also passed it in as a hard coded variable in Karate and it worked fine. However, something about using the 'table' feature seems to change the media type.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The moment you use [`replace`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#replace) the type is converted to string - and this is clearly mentioned in the documentation.

So you have two options: a) type-cast the result of the replace back to JSON b) set the `Content-Type` header manually.

Hope that helps !

Comment: Thanks. Adding this line fixed the issue. I will be sure to look through the document first before opening an issue. I missed that small text you mentioned. And header Content-Type = 'application/json'

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the content type as well by using header keyword as below

Given path 'some/path'

And request { some: 'data' }

**And header Accept = 'application/json'**

When method post

Then status 200

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the recommendation Kanika. After adding your above suggestion, I am still getting a 415 response of "Unsupported Media Type". I should also point out that even when I do not add the header type, by default it is setting it to 'application/json'. based on the response I get back. Additional information I get is "exception":"org.springframework.web.HttpMediaTypeNotSupportedException","message":"Unsupported Media Type"

Comment: Update: The one difference I noticed is for the response, I got a content length of 226 for the request where I got a 415 response. However, when I sent in the same exact POST request as a variable instead of using the above method, the content-length was 49. @PeterThomas